# Replace http or https prefix in string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

i have a php variable which contain url string like this:

```
$url1 = 'http://test1.com/';
$url2 = 'https://test2.com';
$url3 = 'http://test3.com/';
```

i want to replace the http or https prefix with specific string and remove the dash at the end only if the string variable contain dash at the end of the string, for example:

```
$url1 = 'stackoverflow://test1.com';
$url2 = 'stackoverflow://test2.com';
$url3 = 'stackoverflow://test3.com';
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?? Share your code.

Comment: @EmptyBrain nope, im confused on how to do it

Comment: @EmptyBrain Shortcut `https?`

Comment: `echo preg_replace ('/https|http/','stackoverflow','http://test1.com/');`

Comment: @EmptyBrain if i have url like this `https://sdasdahttpol.com/` it will replace the http after the https, and how to remove the `/` in the last string character if only the string last character is `/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try like:

```
$test = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
$test = rtrim(preg_replace ('/https|http/','test',$test,1),'/');
echo $test;
```

Comment: if i have url like this `https://sdasdahttpol.com/` it will replace the http after the https,

Comment: @TinyDancer Check updated answer

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `str_replace` to solve this,

```
 $url = rtrim(str_replace(['http://', 'https://', ], 'stackoverflow://', $url), '/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$url1 = 'http://test1.com/';   
echo str_replace(['http://', 'https://'],'',$url1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
echo reConstructUrl('http://test1.com/','stackoverflow');
function reConstructUrl($url,$replace_string){
  return  rtrim(preg_replace ('/https|http/',$replace_string,$url),'/');
}
```